# In AngularJs how to get label name dynamically from JSON

Tags: angularjs

I am new to AngularJs, can anybody please help me that how to get label name & type dynamically from JSON.

Comment: When you say label name and **type** what do you mean by **type**?

Comment: Not enough information to answer, where are you wanting to put the information you get for example

Comment: Type means like <input type="text">....what actually problem i am facing that i have defined all the label and type in JSON....but i am not able to fetch them....

Answer (score 0):

From the very limited information provided, the only solution I can think of is [angular.forEach](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.forEach)